# Flex - Adding children declared in mxml to a lower level container

Tags: apache-flex

I have a custom component extending Group and containing a viewstack child. The component is coded in actionscript.

When instantiating the component in mxml like so:

```
<components:CustomGroup width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:HBox backgroundColor="0xDDFF11" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <mx:HBox backgroundColor="0x22DD63" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</components:CustomGroup>
```

...I would like to override whatever function that adds the children to the parent Group and add them to the child viewstack instead but I can't seem to find where the adding occurs. Breakpoints in addChild and addElement shows that they are not called during the add.

Any directions would be much appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by overriding the function `mxmlContent(value:Array)`. The array is an array of all the child components declared between the parent tags.

What gets me a little worried is that when perusing inside the adobe source codes step by step, I seemed to have passed it several times but a breakpoint gets only one stop.

Anyways, it'll have to do for the time being unless I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project with the `-keep-generated-actionscript` flag. Now you can see how your mxml code is converted to ActionScript. After some short investigation I found that the [`propertiesFactory`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ComponentDescriptor.html#propertiesFactory) function seems to play a key role during the creation of the components, but I can't find any implementation assignment, because it's just a public function variable. `:-/`

Comment: I already tried doing that but the generated actionscript is a  hard-code translation of the mxml i.e if you put a visual child in the container, the component is added with addElement ; if you put X children, the same code would be repeated X times. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot for mxmlContent(value:Array). Seems like it works for me. This is how I bring view stack nature in Sparc contaner

```
public class DocumentViewer extends SkinnableContainer
{

    [SkinPart(required="true")]
    public var viewStack : ViewStack;

    override public function set mxmlContent(value : Array) : void
    {
        for each (var i : IVisualElement in value)
        {
            addElement(i);
        }
    }

    override public function addElement(element : IVisualElement) : IVisualElement
    {
        if ( element is NavigatorContent )
        {
            return viewStack.addElement(element);
        }
        else
        {
            var nc : NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
            nc.addElement(element);
            return viewStack.addElement(nc);
        }
    }
}
```